# Nested Objection Iteration Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need a little help. I was trying to save user information like full card number, last four digits and unique id, so that I can update it using fetch put request. I was pushing this information in a separate array. it was working fine and now it is giving error `Client id is in invalid TypeError: card_last_digit.push(...).slice is not a function`

I am working on a voice bot project and i am storing last four digits of card in an array. when user say his last four digits then I get the index of unique id after matching last four digit with user card.

How can I achieve this using `Object`. This method is cumbersome but was working fine. Please advice thanks

```
  "objects": [
  {
      "card_number": "3348721238415678",
      "created_at": "2018-10-07T06:42:05.768545",
      "cust_id": "32892",
      "id": 7,
      "resource_uri": "/api/card/7/",
      "status": "active"
  },
  {
      "card_number": "9878675683213843",
      "created_at": "2018-10-09T04:48:18.296061",
      "cust_id": "32892",
      "id": 11,
      "resource_uri": "/api/card/11/",
      "status": "active"
  }
    ];

 let user_cards = [];
 let card_last_digit = [];
 let unique_cust_id = [];
 for (let key in val) {
   user_cards.push(val[key].card_number);
   card_last_digit.push(val[key].card_number).slice(-4);
   unique_cust_id.push((val[key].id));
 }
```

Comment: What is `val` here?

Comment: Slice is not a function of push method, use it instead on array.

Comment: objects is returning from get fetch which is stored in val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get the card object based on the last four digits of the credit card number, a better approach may be to store a mapping of last four digits to card objects. That way, you can directly get the card by key access:

```js
let cards = [{
    "card_number": "3348721238415678",
    "created_at": "2018-10-07T06:42:05.768545",
    "cust_id": "32892",
    "id": 7,
    "resource_uri": "/api/card/7/",
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "card_number": "9878675683213843",
    "created_at": "2018-10-09T04:48:18.296061",
    "cust_id": "32892",
    "id": 11,
    "resource_uri": "/api/card/11/",
    "status": "active"
  }
];

let cardMapping = {};
cards.forEach(card => {
  let lastFourDigits = card.card_number.slice(card.card_number.length - 4);
  cardMapping[lastFourDigits] = card;
});

console.log(cardMapping); // key is last four digits, value is card object
console.log(cardMapping["5678"]); // get card directly from last four digits
```

Comment: This approach looks promising. However, I can only update the data like status from active to block using "id". I need id as well else i have to make another api call to get id ... please advice

Comment: @SumitSingh The ID is still in there. `cardMapping["5678"].id`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var val = {    "objects": [
     {
        "card_number": "3348721238415678",
        "created_at": "2018-10-07T06:42:05.768545",
        "cust_id": "32892",
        "id": 7,
       "resource_uri": "/api/card/7/",
       "status": "active"
   },
    {
      "card_number": "9878675683213843",
      "created_at": "2018-10-09T04:48:18.296061",
       "cust_id": "32892",
       "id": 11,
       "resource_uri": "/api/card/11/",
       "status": "active"
   }
   }
 var user_cards = [];
 var card_last_digit = [];
 var unique_cust_id = [];
 for (var key in val) {
 var obj = val[key];
 obj.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
    user_cards.push(obj[index].card_number);
 card_last_digit.push(obj[index].card_number.slice(-4));
 unique_cust_id.push((obj[index].id));
});

console.log(user_cards);
 console.log(card_last_digit);
console.log(unique_cust_id);
}
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.